# add model relationship without save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the next relationship `User hasMany Contacts`.
In normal situation is use `$user->contacts()->save($contact)` to add and save a contact to the user, but I need to associate contacts to users without save the models (User and Contacts).

**edit:**

I need to build a plant that receives one of such methods and return an XML a collection of templates, only in some of these models will be stored at postiriori.

Comment: is this for creating a user or for updating, because if you update you can user User::push();

Comment: I can not save the models in bd. these will be stored for subsequent in some cases.

Comment: if that is the case i dont know a nother way, but why dont you like the save method?

Comment: I need to build a plant that receives one of such methods and return an XML a collection of templates, only in some of these models will be stored at postiriori.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `associate` on your model with `belongsTo`.

```
$contact= Contact::find(10);

$user->account()->associate($contact);

$user->save(); // You do need to update your user
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: associate method required that contact exists in db, but isn't my  case. contact and user is not saved in db. they will be saver after in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `UserID`, just create a `new Contact;` and make sure to have the correct User ID in the `user_id` column.  Don't even have to touch the `User`.